# An a person without a US citizenship, do I always pay a capital gains tax according to the laws of the country I made the gains in?

Tags: capital-gains-tax, international, germany, new-zealand, immigration

I lived in Germany my whole life. I don't have a US citizenship.
I invested in S&P 500 via the American "Interactive Brokers" for the last 4 years.

Now I want to move to New Zealand.

I want to understand if I can sell my stocks there, will I need to pay the German CGT on them?  Will I need to to pay any other tax when moving?

Comment: Capital gains are usually charged by the country of tax residence. If you move there may be some complications and double taxation that may or may not be mitigated by treaties. Consult with a professional

Comment: @littleadv Agreed in general, with the highly relevant note that typically 'real property' [simplistically: real estate] is taxed first to the country where it resides.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon unless there's a tax treaty, it will be charged by both: the country where the property resides sourced by the property location, and the country where the taxpayer is residing is sourced by the taxpayer residence. For intangibles (like securities) since there's no physical location for the property, only the taxpayer's residence matters. But even that has some caveats and some countries handle things differently. Bottom line, hard to give a generic answer without knowing the details of the investment, tax status, tax treaties, etc.

Comment: So @littleadv, it sounds like I should just sell the bonds now? Dont see what I have to lose by doing that.

Comment: @johngoodheart again, it's hard for me to answer that without knowing the specifics of your situation, and in general a consultation with an international tax adviser would be a good idea before a relocation regardless.

Comment: @littleadv totally agree - that's why I said "Taxed 'first' in country where it resides", meaning that the other country would likely grant credit for taxes paid up to that amount [ie: if both countries had the same tax structure, only the one where the property exists likely claims tax; if the other country has a higher tax rate there might be a bump of additional tax to that other country]. As you say, this is entirely Treaty dependant, so I speak here solely in generalities.

Comment: @johngoodheart are your investments held in a German tax-advantaged account structure [I am not familiar with that system]? Do you plan to return there? Is there a difference in tax paid in Germany on early liquidation vs holding to maturity for bonds? There are a lot of factors that could impact things.

Comment: I don't have a tax-advantaged account. I don't plan to return in the foreseeable future (expect to visit), and i don't think there isn't a difference between holding bonds to maturity or liquidating them, but it doesn't matter because my investment is only in stocks.